# Need to print this array vertically

Tags: javascript

I need to print this array vertically in the div with ID 'stopwatch'

```
var klas = ['Nick Arts', 'Thijs Assmann', 'Rick Bats', 'Kim Cobben', 'Richard van Dartel', 'Dennis van Empel', 'Luuk van Gennip', 'Florent Guichard', 'Mahamed Hassan', 'Stijn Hendriks', 'Dirk van Herpen', 'Daniël Kartotaroeno', 'Tony van Klink', 'Stephan Klomp', 'Twan Korthout', 'Max Lenssen', 'Aron van der Linden', 'Aron de Looijer', 'Anil Manbodh', 'Sietse Manders', 'Ben Moerkens', 'Sven van Mourik', 'Teun Salters', 'Sven Slijkoord', 'Daan Soeten', 'Joey van Straalen', 'Koen van Veen', 'Maxim Westbroek'];
```

I want it like

```
Nick Arts
Thijs Assmann
```

Comment: `"<div>"+klas.join("</div><div>") + "</div>"; `

Answer (score 8):

Just use [`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) for it:

```js
var klas = ['Nick Arts', 'Thijs Assmann', 'Rick Bats', 'Kim Cobben', 'Richard van Dartel', 'Dennis van Empel', 'Luuk van Gennip', 'Florent Guichard', 'Mahamed Hassan', 'Stijn Hendriks', 'Dirk van Herpen', 'Daniël Kartotaroeno', 'Tony van Klink', 'Stephan Klomp', 'Twan Korthout', 'Max Lenssen', 'Aron van der Linden', 'Aron de Looijer', 'Anil Manbodh', 'Sietse Manders', 'Ben Moerkens', 'Sven van Mourik', 'Teun Salters', 'Sven Slijkoord', 'Daan Soeten', 'Joey van Straalen', 'Koen van Veen', 'Maxim Westbroek'];

document.getElementById('stopwatch').innerHTML = klas.join('<br>');
```

```html
<div id="stopwatch"></div>
```

Comment: document.write? really?

Answer (score 0):

```
var klas = ['Nick Arts', 'Thijs Assmann', 'Rick Bats', 'Kim Cobben', 'Richard van Dartel', 'Dennis van Empel', 'Luuk van Gennip', 'Florent Guichard', 'Mahamed Hassan', 'Stijn Hendriks', 'Dirk van Herpen', 'Daniël Kartotaroeno', 'Tony van Klink', 'Stephan Klomp', 'Twan Korthout', 'Max Lenssen', 'Aron van der Linden', 'Aron de Looijer', 'Anil Manbodh', 'Sietse Manders', 'Ben Moerkens', 'Sven van Mourik', 'Teun Salters', 'Sven Slijkoord', 'Daan Soeten', 'Joey van Straalen', 'Koen van Veen', 'Maxim Westbroek'];

element.textContent = klas.join('\n')
```